# Finding a curve, $H$, obtained by applying a function $R$ to all points in a function $G$

Tags: linear-algebra, functions

I am given a function $R: \mathbb{R}^2 \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^2$ defined by $R(x,y)=\frac{1}{\sqrt2}(x+y,y-x)$, and $G=\{(x,\frac{1}{x})|x\in\mathbb{R}\backslash \{0\}\}$, which is the graph of the reciprocal function $f(x)=\frac{1}{x}$.

I am asked to find a curve $H$ which is obtained by applying $R$ to all points in $G$ and to show that the curve is a hyperbola.

I tried subbing in $x$ and $\frac{1}{x}$ into $R$ but not sure how I'm supposed to obtain a hyperbola from that.

Comment: My guess would be that R is a linear transformation, and therefore G which is already a hyperbole stays a hyperbole.

Comment: I need to express the hyperbola as $\frac{x^2}{a^2}-\frac{y^2}{b^2}=1$, so I'm not sure where to go from there.

Comment: I'm not sure it can be expressed like that. I don't think its axis are going to be aligned with the x and y axis...

Comment: I think I figured it out. I'll have a go at subbing in $R(x,\frac{1}{x})$ then calculating $x^2-y^2$ and solving that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Riccardo Orlando has stated, $R$ is a linear transformation. In fact, it is a rotation by $45^\circ$ clockwise. So contrary to Riccardo's expectation, the rotated hyperbola can indeed be expressed in the normal form, as this is exactly the rotation needed to align the hyperbola's axes of symmetry with the coordinate axes.

So let's try it. To clarify matters, I'm going to express the points of $G$ in terms of a parameter $t$ instead of $x$: $G = \{(t, 1/t) \mid t \ne 0\}$
The image of the point $(t, 1/t)$ under $R$ is $\frac 1 {\sqrt 2}(t + 1/t, 1/t - t)$. That is:
$$\sqrt 2 x = t + 1/t\\\sqrt 2 y = 1/t -t$$
This is a parametric expression for the curve. Now you want an expression in terms of just $x$ and $y$. Well, we have two equations in 3 unknowns, so it should be possible to eliminate one of the variables. Let's start by taking the sum and difference of the two equations:
$$\sqrt 2(x + y) = 2/t\\
\sqrt 2(x - y) = 2t$$
or
$$x + y = \frac{\sqrt 2}t\\\frac{x - y}{\sqrt 2} =  t$$

and so
$$ x + y = \frac 2{x - y}$$
or $$x^2 - y^2 = 2$$

This shows that the image of every point of $G$ under $R$ lies on the hyperbola $x^2 - y^2 = 2$.

Can you see how to go the other way - to prove that every point of the hyperbola $x^2 - y^2 = 2$ is the image under $R$ of $(t, 1/t)$ for some value $t$?

Comment: Okay I get that, thank you

Comment: My name had a double c... Can you fix it? Other than that, excellent answer :)

Comment: @RiccardoOrlando - My apologies for not checking carefully!